# Can't import tensorflow_federated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

An attribute Error raised when importing tensorflow_federated on colab though I did install it.

`!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated`

`import tensorflow as tf`

`import tensorflow_federated as tff`

--> import tensorflow_federated as tff : AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'

how can I solve it?
Thank you!

`!pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated`

`import tensorflow as tf`

`import tensorflow_federated as tff`

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing,

> import tensorflow_federated as tff : AttributeError: module 'numpy'
> has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'

which mentions "module 'numpy' has no attribute '_no_nep50_warning'," is likely due to a compatibility issue between the versions of NumPy and TensorFlow Federated (TFF). To resolve this, you can follow a few steps.

1.Update the Numpy (Make sure you have the latest version of NumPy installed)

> !pip install --upgrade
> numpy

2.Reinstall TensorFlow Federated:

> !pip uninstall -y
> tensorflow-federated
>
> !pip install
> tensorflow-federated

3.Import TensorFlow Federated:

> import tensorflow_federated as tff

**You can refer to the gist as given:-** [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10_QNtzWjiZhfkh4XMJdEdonqefqdffeY?usp=sharing)